# What is meant by Jenkins API and what it's use?

Tags: jenkins

I've been asked to work on 'Jenkins API' and I had looked into few sites to understand about 'Jenkins API' but

Please explain me the following by providing simple examples

```
1)  What's meant by Jenkins API?   Is it a plug-in available in Jenkins? For What reason it is used? 
2)  Can I use 'Jenkins API' for any type of job (or) should it be used for particular types of job?
3)  What's meant by 'API URL' in Jenkins?  I see URL for all options available in 'jenkins'.  What's special about 'API URL' in Jenkins?
4)  Is there anything known as 'Jenkins callback API'?
```

Sorry had this been answered somewhere else in this forum

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check the official documention:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Is that enough or is it something else you need?

Comment: I'll take a look.  Thank you